# How to integrate mozilla open badges with our website?

Tags: java, php, javascript, browser, mozilla

I want to integrate Mozilla open badges with my website? what steps should i follow to integrate open badges with my website. I googled alot but didn't get any success, if some one will help, Million of thanks in advance...

Comment: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Badges/GetStarted , deeper reading sections, keyword is API